# setting the width and height of table data

Tags: javascript, css, html

This one is a simple one I know but I am stuck and lost for ideas. I have a table of contents that changes dynamically for different values. So the width and height of the table data is not definite. I want to set the width and height of this table data.

```
<td style='width:30px; max-height:10px; overflow:auto; '>
<input type='checkbox' name='facets'>
+ facetList[count].term + "(" + facetList[count].count + ")" + "</td>";
```

But it gives me the output like in the snap that Ive attached. whats wrong with my CSS?[image]

Comment: I am not sure, what your problem. Are you not happy with space in rows, when there is multiple line text in a column?

Comment: and what is your purpose of using **overflow:auto;** in your code

Comment: u cn see that in the third coloumn..

Comment: and that was a mistake... my original doc has overflow as hidden..

Comment: from the pic, u cn guess that its not a 30px width data... and cetainly nt a 10px height..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try dynamic width and heights ?
Like

```
style="width: 80%; max-height: 10%"
```